# Extract values from URls using regular expression

Tags: java, regex

I have the following `Pattern`

```
http://abc.com/#!/[0-9a-z]
http://abc.com/#!/search/%23[^.]
```

So the first pattern identify the URL of a user and second URL identifies search parameters.

I can check whether the pattern belongs to user or search query using `Pattern` and `Matcher` class in Java. How can i extract the values of user or search term?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use capturing group.  Look at [Java regular expressions: capturing groups](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/regular_expressions/capturing_groups.shtml) for details.